# Pass ViewData to all actions without having to write it every time

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

All, I am simply trying to read a custom value from a loaded .config file into an MVC project.

So I set a value such as the below in my added .config file:

```
"AppSettings": {
    "Title": "Mobile Site"
  }
```

I've made a base controller to set the values

```
public abstract class ControllerBase : Controller
{
    protected Models.AppSettings _appSettings;
    private IConfiguration _config;
    public ControllerBase(IConfiguration config)
    {
        _config = config;
        _appSettings = new Models.AppSettings();
        _appSettings.SiteTitle = _config.GetSection("AppSettings").GetSection("Title").Value;

        ViewBag.Settings = _appSettings;
    }
}
```

This I can also confirm is working. The values are pulled through if I simply set the viewbag data in one of my actions.

```
public class AppController : ControllerBase
{
    public AppController(IConfiguration config) : base(config)
    {

    }
    // GET: /<controller>/
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["Settings"] = _appSettings;
        return View("Index");
    }
```

I can access the values in the view this way, but as the values I'm currenlty adding are simply what the site title is (so I can config these things in a simple .config file) I want stuff like the site title to be passed to every action without having to specifically pass it each and every time for every single action.

I tried following a video showing this working by settings this in the view:

```
@{
    ViewData["Logo"] = "~/img/bird.png";
    ViewData["Icon"] = "~/img/logo.ico";
    var Settings = ((Mobile.Models.AppSettings)ViewBag.Settings);
}
```

But the page will fail to load properly if again, I dont specify the settings within the action loading the page.

How can this be done? Can this be done any more?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MVC Core approach to implementing aspect-oriented functionality is the same as in MVC 5. There are at least two ways to inject a code before/after each action:

А. Override `OnActionExecuting` in your `ControllerBase`:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
    ViewBag.foo = "1";
}
```

OR

B. Add `ActionFilter` to the controller (the filter has to be registered in DI):

```
public class TestFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        ViewBag.foo = "1";
        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
}

[ServiceFilter(typeof(TestFilter))]
public class TestController : Controller
{
}
```

More examples: [Asp.net Core 1.0 Action Filters](https://damienbod.com/2015/09/15/asp-net-5-action-filters/). The second way is more flexible (for example, you can easily add the filter to a particular action).

Comment: I had to add the below to ConfgureServices to get it to work but yep, thats done it.

services.AddScoped<SiteSetting>();

SiteSetting is the name of my filter attribute. Thank you, this was looking impossible for what sounded so simple, let me change the site title etc from a custom config file. Madness.